# Typeset functions with PythonTeX and execute them in console afterwards

Tags: pythontex

I have the following python source code:

```
def modulo(a, n):
    return a % n

print(modulo(3, 10))
print(modulo(10, 10))
print(modulo(11, 10))
```

The first function definition gives a hint about the implementation and the calls below show exemplary usage / output.

I want to typeset this the following way (so people can copy&paste the implementation and see some live output):

```
def modulo(a, n):
    return a % n

>>> print(modulo(3, 10))
3
>>> print(modulo(10, 10))
0
>>> print(modulo(11, 10))
1
```

I failed to create this using PythonTeX.

```
\begin{pyblock}[mysession][]
def modulo(a, n):
    return a % n

\end{pyblock}

\begin{pyconsole}[mysession][]
print(modulo(3, 10))
print(modulo(10, 10))
print(modulo(11, 10))

\end{pyconsole}
```

This gives me

```
def modulo(a, n):
    return a % n

>>> print(modulo(3, 10))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'modulo' is not defined
>>> print(modulo(10, 10))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'modulo' is not defined
>>> print(modulo(11, 10))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'modulo' is not defined
```

The [documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/pythontex/pythontex.pdf) mentions sessions, where code is run in parallel so I put those code snippets explicitly into the same session (even though per default both are run in `default`).

I definitely need a *PythonTeX* solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Console code and normal code each have their own *separate* `default` sessions. All commands/environments starting with `pycon` execute completely separately from those beginning with `py`. There is no overlap between them.

A feature to do what you want [has been requested](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/issues/55) and will be implemented in an upcoming release of PythonTeX.  In the meantime, you can probably do what you want with this workaround, [copied from that feature request](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/issues/55#issuecomment-73303368).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pythontex}

\newenvironment{pyconcodeblock}%
 {\VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{VerbatimOut}{temp.py}}%
 {\end{VerbatimOut}%
  \pyconc{exec(compile(open('temp.py', 'rb').read(), 'temp.py', 'exec'))}%
  \inputpygments{python}{temp.py}}

\begin{document}

\begin{pyconcodeblock}
def foo(x):
    return 2*x
\end{pyconcodeblock}

\begin{pyconsole}
x = 10
foo(x)
\end{pyconsole}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect answer resolving my session confusion and providing a workaround. The workaround does not work for me. Either the file temp.py does not exist or an AttributeError is raised. But this will be discussed on github. Thanks!