# Pythontex and latexmk

Tags: latexmk, pythontex

The compilation works fine if I use LaTeX, Python, and then LaTeX,  with the command for Python :

```
python  "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\pythontex\pythontex.py"
```

But I can't use `latexmk` to make the same thing :

If I try:

```
latexmk  -r C:\latexmk\LatexMk.txt  essai.tex
```

with in the file `LatexMk.txt`:

```
add_cus_dep('pytxcode', 'tex', 0, 'pythontex');
sub pythontex { return system("pythontex \"$_[0]\""); }
$aux_dir = 'auxiliaire2';
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex-synctex=1 --shell-escape %O %S';
$latex = 'latex -synctex=1 --shell-escape %O %S';
```

then LaTeX compiles fine, but when PythonTeX  runs, an arror occurs:

```
Package PythonTeX Warning: Non-existent Pygments content on input line 11.
```

and I obtain as result

```
??PythonTex??
```

I don't understand why.
I'm using Windows 10.

More precisely, essai.tex is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\begin{document}
Here's the code in the document
\begin{pyverbatim}
        return '\\SI{' + str(var) + '}{' + unit + '}'
\end{pyverbatim}
\end{document}
```

and the console's ouput is :

```
'Custom dependency list:
  pytxcode tex 0 pythontex
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 17 Jan. 2018, version: 4.55.
Rule 'latex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'E:\professionnel\_BTS_SIO_1_U_22_algo\TD_6\essai.tex'
      'essai.tex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'latex'
------------
------------
Running 'latex -synctex=1 --shell-escape  -recorder -aux- 
directory="auxiliaire2"  
"E:\professionnel\_BTS_SIO_1_U_22_algo\TD_6\essai.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'latex'...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6630 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(E:/professionnel/_BTS_SIO_1_U_22_algo/TD_6/essai.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
```

Comment from me : I cut lines where Miktex works...

```
No file pythontex-files-essai/essai.pytxmcr.
Run PythonTeX to create it.

Package PythonTeX Warning: Non-existent Pygments content on input line 11.

[1] (E:\professionnel\_BTS_SIO_1_U_22_algo\TD_6\auxiliaire2\essai.aux) )
Output written on essai.dvi (1 page, 480 bytes).
SyncTeX written on essai.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on 
E:\professionnel\_BTS_SIO_1_U_22_algo\TD_6\auxiliaire2\es
sai.log.
===========Latexmk: Missing input file: 'pythontex-files-
```

essai/essai.pytxmcr' from line
      'No file pythontex-files-essai/essai.pytxmcr.'
    Latexmk: Missing input file: 'pythontex-files-essai/essai.pytxmcr' from line
      'No file pythontex-files-essai/essai.pytxmcr.'
    Latexmk: Log file says output to 'essai.dvi'
    === TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
        Latexmk: All targets (essai.dvi) are up-to-date'

Comment: If I use `add_cus_dep('pytxcode', 'tex', 0, 'pytxcode2tex');
sub pytxcode2tex { return system("pythontex \"$_[0]\""); }` I have no problem. Note: there is an added space between the `pythontex` and the `\"` in the rule.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.With an added space as you said : same result.

Comment: The console's output seems linked to the missing of pygments for python : Run PythonTeX to create it.
Package PythonTeX Warning: Non-existent Pygments content on input line 11.

Comment: but Pygments is installed  .

Comment: I think that Miktex chose a Python's installation in my PC wich hasn't Pygments installed. But where is it? Where can I change   Python's installation?

Comment: perhaps use [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download) for a comprehensive Python distribution. But I don't know about Windows.

Comment: @jfbu Thanks you! I installed Anaconda , uninstalled Miktex 64 bits, and installed Miktex 32bits : I obtained the same result.

Comment: to avoid the missing pygments error, I changed pythontex to pythontex3 in .latexmkrc file; might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is discussed in https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/issues/132#issuecomment-492531792 .

With your configuration, after the first time where you manually run `pythontex`, subsequent runs with `latexmk` should work automatically.

That having said, if you want to make it work in the first run as well, the linked GitHub issue above has a solution -- put the following in `latexmkrc`:

```perl
# Support for pythontex in v. 0.16 or higher, with latexmk 4.62 or higher
#
# What these definitions provide/do:
# 1. Variable specifying command string for invoking pythontex
# 2. Addition to %extra_rule_spec of template for pythontex rule. This
#    tells latexmkrc to create the rule when it is initializing for
#    processing a TeX file.
# 3. A subroutine mypythontex that the pythontex rule is defined to
#    call. This runs pythontex and then sets dependency information.
# 4. Settings for the files generated by the pythontex package and the
#    pythontex program so that the files are deleted in a clean-up
#    operation.

$clean_ext .= " pythontex-files-%R/* pythontex-files-%R";
push @generated_exts, 'pytxcode';

$pythontex = 'pythontex %O %S';
$extra_rule_spec{'pythontex'}  = [ 'internal', '', 'mypythontex', "%Y%R.pytxcode",  "%Ypythontex-files-%R/%R.pytxmcr",    "%R", 1 ];

sub mypythontex {
   my $result_dir = $aux_dir1."pythontex-files-$$Pbase";
   my $ret = Run_subst( $pythontex, 2 );
   rdb_add_generated( glob "$result_dir/*" );
   open( my $fh, "<", $$Pdest );
   if ($fh) {
      while (<$fh>) {
         if ( /^%PythonTeX dependency:\s+'([^']+)';/ ) {
         print "Found pythontex dependency '$1'\n";
             rdb_ensure_file( $rule, $aux_dir1.$1 );
     }
      }
      undef $fh;
   }
   else {
       warn "mypythontex: I could not read '$$Pdest'\n",
            "  to check dependencies\n";
   }
   return $ret;
}
```

As far as I can see, the normal `add_cus_dep` cannot be used to "properly" handle this because the location of the source file `a.pytxcode` is different from that of the target file `pythontex-files-a/a.pytxmcr`.

I unfortunately can't find documentation of `%extra_rule_spec`. ([latexmk with pythontex, lualatex and long name not working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/683374/latexmk-with-pythontex-lualatex-and-long-name-not-working)  may have some explanation.)

---

An alternative method is to use the other method explained in pythontex manual:

[image: pythontex manual]

The method was originally made for the case where `--output-directory` is not the normal one, however it doesn't really matter -- it allows `add_cus_dep` to work properly by moving the `a.pytxmcr` to the **current directory**, however the disadvantage, as mentioned, is **the other auxiliary files (`a.pytxpyg`,
`pythontex_data.pkl`) is also moved to the current directory**.