# PythonTex: Mixing console and normal code session, with unicode characters

Tags: unicode, pythontex

I'm trying to do pretty much the same thing as in here [Typeset functions with PythonTeX and execute them in console afterwards](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240812), except that I'd like to use some unicode characters (French accents: é, è, etc.). However, the answer provided there fails to work in that case (during the `pythontex` run).

See the following MWE (where if I change `Résultat` in `Resultat`, it works fine):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\newenvironment{pyconcodeblock}%
 {\VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{VerbatimOut}{temp.py}}%
 {\end{VerbatimOut}%
  \pyconc{exec(compile(open('temp.py', 'rb').read(), 'temp.py', 'exec'))}%
  \inputpygments{python}{temp.py}}

\begin{document}

\begin{pyconcodeblock}
def foo(x):
    print("Résultat :", 2*x)
\end{pyconcodeblock}

\begin{pyconsole}
x = 10
foo(x)
\end{pyconsole}

\end{document}
```

(I'm using PDFLaTeX and Python 3 provided by WinPython.)

Would you have any ideas to make this works?

PS: the entire message I get when running pythontex is:

```
This is PythonTeX 0.15
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\multiprocessing
\pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "c:\texlive\2016\texmf-dist\scripts\pythontex\pythontex3.py", line 2273,
in do_pygments
    content = f.read()
  File "C:\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\codecs.py", lin
e 319, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 24: invalid
 continuation byte
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\texlive\2016\texmf-dist\scripts\pythontex\pythontex.py", line 62, in
<module>
    pythontex.main()
  File "c:\texlive\2016\texmf-dist\scripts\pythontex\pythontex3.py", line 2676,
in main
    do_multiprocessing(data, temp_data, old_data, engine_dict)
  File "c:\texlive\2016\texmf-dist\scripts\pythontex\pythontex3.py", line 1369,
in do_multiprocessing
    result = task.get()
  File "C:\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\multiprocessing
\pool.py", line 599, in get
    raise self._value
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 24: invalid
 continuation byte
C:\texlive\2016\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:679: command failed with exit code 1:
python.exe c:\texlive\2016\texmf-dist\scripts\pythontex\pythontex.py test.tex
```

Comment: I am a Python ignorant but at least in the `pycode` environment  the string`u"Résultat :"` (note the prefix `u`) is printed correctly, so I see  `Résultat : 20`  in the PDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the `VerbatimOut` environment (from `fancyvrb`) not properly supporting UTF-8.  You can patch it by adding this to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\FVB@VerbatimOut#1{%
  \@bsphack
  \begingroup
  \FV@UseKeyValues
  \FV@DefineWhiteSpace
  \def\FV@Space{\space}%
  \FV@DefineTabOut
  \def\FV@ProcessLine##1{\immediate\write\FV@OutFile{\detokenize{##1}}}%
  \immediate\openout\FV@OutFile #1\relax
  \let\FV@FontScanPrep\relax
  \let\@noligs\relax
  \FV@Scan}
\makeatother
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work; in the code part I get `Resultat` without the accented letter and, worse, the console prints `R\xc3\xa9sultat`

Comment: @egreg This is working well for me (I do have, however, to manually delete the `pythontex-files` directory after any change in the `pyconcodeblock` environment, otherwise the change doesn't appear).

Comment: @mathieu2l I still get `R\xc3\xa9sultat` in the console output.

Comment: @egreg Could this be related to the version of Python? (I never used Python 2 but it is my understanding that Python 2 doesn't provide natively a full UTF-8 support... not sure)

Comment: If I use Python3, the console output shows `RÃ©sultat`

Comment: @mathieu2l Having the code update automatically isn't possible with the temp file approach. I hope to add proper support for mixing normal code and console code eventually, but until then these sorts of things are really forcing the console support to do things it was never designed for.

Comment: @egreg The hex escapes are the default for Python 2 console output. I'm not sure what would be causing your Python 3 result, but it's probably something with encodings. I've tested under Windows with Python 3 and under Ubuntu with Python 2 and 3, and it works with all of those (with the different Python 2 behavior).

Comment: @G.Poore That kind of support would be really great. Just to clarify why I do this (in the hope it helps designing the feature): this is for correcting exercises given to beginners in Python (I write a function and then I also write the result of its test in the console).